# Maven - Deploy WAR to a specific folder also

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I need to know how to instruct maven to deploy a ROOT.war into `/deployments` folder while keeping the standard `/src/main/webapp` deployement directory.

Here is the profile that I need to deal with:

```
<profile>
          <id>sdk</id>
          <build>
              <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>${gae.version}</version>
                      <configuration>
                          <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                      </configuration>
                  </plugin>
                  <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>${version.gwt}</version>
                      <executions>
                          <execution>
                              <!-- gwt:compile happens just before package phase -->
                              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                              <goals>
                                  <goal>compile</goal>
                              </goals>
                          </execution>
                      </executions>
                      <configuration>
                          <modules>
                              <!-- gwt module inherits Core gwt module therefore both will be gwt:compiled -->
                              <module>org.example.App</module>
                          </modules>
                          <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
                          <!--<logLevel>WARN</logLevel>-->
                          <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                          <appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
                          <!-- tell the gwt plugin that the webapp source resides in src/main/webapp -->
                          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                          <!-- tell the gwt plugin that dev mode should be run using the webapp that resides in target/${webappDirectory} -->
                          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                          <!-- Normally the gwt maven plugin executes dev mode using a builtin jetty server.
                               This config property instructs the gwt maven plugin to execute dev mode using the
                               jetty server supplied by the appengine sdk. -->
                          <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                      </configuration>
                  </plugin>
              </plugins>
          </build>
      </profile>
```

Now, my app being deployed in Openshift I need to have this profile also:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
     <id>openshift</id>
     <build>
        <finalName>OpenShift template</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
              <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Just putting the `maven-war-plugin` alonside with the `gwt-maven-plugin` doesn't work and `web.xml` is not being copied and so forth. So I need to modify the `gwt-maven-plugin` settings instead.
The question here now is

- How to make the `gwt-maven-plugin` to also deploy similar to this
  openshift profile? To deploy `ROOT.war` into the `/deployments` folder

Comment: I need clarification. You want to "deploy", you mean create a .war file? by having `maven-war-plugin` and `gwt-maven-plugin`, what you mean? You mean that the output from the `gwt-maven-plugin` is not packed by the `maven-war-plugin`? Are you using Eclipse environment with m2e-wtp plugin? I'd run the war and use a ant task (within the maven build) to copy the war to the `/deployments` folder. But I'm confused, your war is being properly packed and you just want it copied to the specific folder or you're also having troubles to compile the GWT application and pack it with the war?

Comment: There are two profiles here. One is the 'openshift' which has the maven-war-plugin and the 'sdk' profile which has the gwt-maven-plugin. When the app is in the 'sdk' profile it does not build the ROOT.war in the deployments folder. If I put the maven-war-plugin into the sdk profile, it breaks somehow that web.xml is not copied. So the question is how to make gwt-maven-plugin build the ROOT.war without me adding the maven-war-plugin into 'sdk' profile

Comment: That's why I'm confused, `gwt-maven-plugin` is not designed to pack wars, just to compile GWT applications, after it finishes executing, it output the GWT application at the folder you specified at the plugin configuration.

Comment: Yes, that is why I need to have the profile 'sdk' to also output ROOT.war under /deployments folder, as this is needed for my GWT Openshift app. (Hopefully). Now I can't put the gwt-maven-plugin into the openshift profile as Openshift does not have the resources to run and build gwt on the cloud servers.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce this myself, you will have to try debug the maven build yourself. Add the war plugin at the `sdk` profile too. Run, read the debug log, where your GWT application is being placed, see where is your webapp is, see what your `war-maven-plugin` is packing. Maybe you need a `<webResources>` tag to add the webapp resouces (the web.xml) that are missing from the war.